# Is there something wrong with saying 千万不喜欢 to mean I absolutely do not like something?

Tags: word-choice

This sentence seems unproblematic:

> 我不喜欢抽烟。
>   I don't like smoking.

But I want to emphasize the strength of my dislike:

> 我[千万](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8D%83%E4%B8%87)不喜欢抽烟。

However, searching for [`"千万不喜欢"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E5%8D%83%E4%B8%87%E4%B8%8D%E5%96%9C%E6%AC%A2%22) on Baidu doesn't give many hits, so it seems like is very unusual.  However there seems to be plenty of hits for [`"千万不要"`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E5%8D%83%E4%B8%87%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%22).  I don't really see the distinction.

**Question**: Is there something wrong with saying 千万不喜欢 to mean I absolutely do not like something?

Comment: absolutely 翻译为“绝对”，你为什么要用“千万”？

Comment: You actually can't say “千万不喜欢”. "千万“ can only be used in preceding to "不要" or "（要）记得"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other answers pointed out, 千万 is usually used as a warning. 千万 typically implies a reason why you should or should not do something (Otherwise you would suffer a certain consequence). E.g. 你走路时千万要小心 (否则很容易摔倒).

If you want to emphasize the strength of your dislike in your example, you can say: 我真不喜欢抽烟。// I really don't like smoking.

You can use other words to express your dislike too, such as 讨厌. E.g. 我讨厌抽烟。 Add more emphasis: 我很讨厌抽烟。 ,  我非常讨厌抽烟。 or 我特别讨厌抽烟。 The extremest could be 我真的是非常，非常，非常讨厌抽烟!!!

P.S. In English, "I absolutely do not like something" is probably an idiomatic way. But when it's translated into Chinese, it might not be idiomatic any more because both languages expresses things in different manners. In this case, a direct translation would be: 我绝对不喜欢抽烟. But the sentence's rarely been said in practice. You are more likely to hear 我一点都不喜欢抽烟 from a Chinese speaker.

Comment: Although: if someone’s offering you a smoke - there’s no need to be a jerk and tell them how much you dislike smoking. You can just simply decline and tell them you (不抽) don’t smoke.

Answer (score 2):

"absolutely" is translated as "绝对"

> 我不喜欢抽烟 (I don't like to smoke) --> 我絕對不喜欢抽烟 (I absolutely don't like to smoke)

"千万" functions like "must" in English. It is mainly used in serious warning/ reminder for a future action

> 千万 doesn't usually be used on it's own to modify a verb phrase, it is usually used to emphasize 要, /別 or 不能/不可
>
> 千万要 - absolutely need to
>
> 千万不要/ 千万別 - absolutely don't
>
> 千万不能/ 千万不可 - absolutely cannot
>
> 千万不喜欢抽烟 is ungrammatical because it miss a verb like 不要

Correct usage of 千万:

"这事情千万不可泄漏出去" - "This matter must not be leaked out". (serious warning for not to leak out in the future)

"面见皇上时说话千万要小心" - "When you meet his majesty, you must speak carefully" (serious reminder for speak carefully in an up coming event)

千万不要抽烟 (you must not smoke) implies you are not smoking now and warning you not to in the future

千万別喜欢上抽烟 (you must not become addictive to smoking) implies you are not addictive to smoking now and warning you not to in the future

Answer (score 2):

Based on examples, `千万不`， `千万别` are generally used when you give suggestions to others. e.g.

`（你｜ta）千万别喜欢抽烟`

`（你｜ta）千万不要喜欢抽烟`

`（你｜ta）千万别去`

It also implies that the like/dislike is what you're hoping for from another person.

In your example, you want to emphasize your dislike, and you know that you don't like smoking.

This is my observation, and you can try to apply this to other examples and see if it's applicable.